# Instalação OpenBDT

Tags: testes-automatizados

Começando nessa vida hoje, foi disponibilizado como ferramenta de trabalho o OpenBDT, ao final de toda a instalação, não estou conseguindo criar um projeto, alguém consegue me ajudar?

[image: Tela da mensagem]

Answer (score -2):

Dar uma olhada neste link para ver se resolve seu problema...

https://github.com/OpenBDT/archetype/wiki/gerando-meu-primeiro-projeto-com-o-archetype-OpenBDT

Comment: Adriano, você inseriu no campo resposta um comentário, assim que tiver reputação necessária poderá publicar nos comentários.